# Remastersys: how to make the .iso smaller than 700MB?

Tags: 10.10, live-cd, iso, remastersys

I'm trying to create a Live CD .iso image of my Ubuntu 10.10 installation with Remastersys.

The problem with this, is that it creates .iso's of about 750-770 MBs, I need the images to be less than 700MB so that I can burn the .iso on a CD.

*How can I do this?* Can I remove some programs or some features of Ubuntu to lessen the space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a base install of ubuntu (from the alternate CD), and then install the applications you need to make up your system.

You can also remove some of the unnecessary packages (documentation, etc) from the default install that you don't want.
I've not been able to make it below 700MB before, but I've come close (I had to install some other apps in that situation unfortunately).

Any way you do it, it will produce a safe iso so long as you don't remove the base system (ubuntu--minimal's dependencies should be a good guide).

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it is pretty close to impossible when considering the default cd size before install for Ubuntu is 695 MBS so that gives you 5 mbs to play with, not much room to play... just about anything would push you over 700 mbs...

Answer (score 2):

If you remove programs you will save space, you can also remove documetation, background images, themes and so on, this will save space.